# Images in emailings: to attach or not to attach

Tags: email, email-attachments, newsletter

I like to send my emailings with the images attached (inline). It seems more user friendly, since no one will have to click "show images". I send them with php, but that's not really relevant.

But I feel lonely! Emailings that I receive myself nearly always link the images, rather than attach them.

Now, I have recently picked up my Quest against Spam Scores, and am thus putting everything in question that I'm doing. So I have begun to wonder:

**Is there any benefit (other than network usage) to linking rather than embedding images in an emailing?**

The only thing I can think of is tracking. Anything else? (Do spam filters have a preference?)

Answer (score 0):

Attaching images, at least from what I've seen, is generally frowned upon, basically due to the security issues that may or may not surround them.

I may be wrong, but major e-mail providers tend to block e-mails with attachments, plus since its not the standard, people tend to ignore, or be wary of e-mail subscriptions with attachments.

I'm not entirely sure how you would have tracking (then again, I'm not sure how you are implementing this), but yes, spam filters prefer links to attachments

Comment: With 'tracking' I meant that embedding images, rather than attaching them, allows to track who views your emails (or at least its images), while this is not possible when you attach them. 

As for spam filters prefering links, I must say I'm still a bit sceptical... Might you have a source?